# TableView interactive use

Tags: dynamic, data

I am attempting to use [`TableView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableView.html) (added in version 12.1) interactively to edit data and save the edited data.  The following works.

```
tv = TableView[{{"Paris", "France", 2200000}, {"New York", "US", 8500000}, {"Beijing", "China", 21700000}}, AllowedDimensions -> {3, 3}]
```

I evaluate this command to produce the editable `TableView` object.  I make the necessary edits to the cells in this displayed "Out" table and then evaluate this "Out" object (which turns it into an "In" object and produces a new "Out" object).  The new "Out" object has the corrected values, which I save using

```
tv2 = Setting[%]
```

However, I have the impression that there must be a better way to do this using `TableView[Dynamic[tv]]`.  However when I try this I get an error message "Cannot assign to raw object".

As trivial as this may be, can someone give me an example of how to correctly use `TableView` to interactively edit and save a data matrix?

Comment: You need `data = {{"Paris", "France", 2200000}, ...}; TableView[Dynamic[data]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below might help. Asked a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226153/tableview-and-dynamic).  Code might be a little more complicated than it needs to be. Code let's the user edit points with TableView or with Locator Points.

[image]

```
makeXYplots[xy_] := Module[{}, ListLinePlot[xy
   , PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 1.01}, {-0.05, 1.05}}
   , Frame -> True
   , GridLines -> Automatic
   , ImageSize -> 600
   , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[xy] }] ]
makeXYtable[xy_] := Module[{}, TableForm[xy]] 
initPts[n_Integer] := Module[{xVals, yVals },
  xVals = Sort@Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], 0.01];
  yVals = Sort@Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n], 0.01];
   Transpose[{xVals, yVals}]
  ]
exportPoints[pts_] := Module[{fileName,  dir},
  dir = If[ Quiet@NotebookDirectory[] =!= $Failed, 
    NotebookDirectory[], $HomeDirectory];
  fileName = SystemDialogInput["FileSave", dir];
  If[fileName =!= $Canceled , Export[fileName, pts ], {} ]
  ]

testManip = DynamicModule[{xyData, iCount, status, lcpBackground},
   Manipulate[
    iCount = iUpdate ;
    lcpBackground = Dynamic[makeXYplots[xyData]] ;
    If[inputType == 0,
     Row[{LocatorPane[ Dynamic[xyData], lcpBackground, 
        LocatorAutoCreate -> True, ContinuousAction -> False]
       , Spacer[10]
       , Dynamic[Framed[ makeXYtable[xyData]]]
        }] ,
     Row[{Dynamic[makeXYplots[xyData]]
       , Spacer[10]
       , TableView[Dynamic[xyData] , Number, 
        AllowedDimensions -> {2, Dynamic[Length@xyData]} ]
        }] 
     ]
    , Delimiter(*=======================*)
    , Style["Calculation Control", Black, Italic,  12]
    , {{inputType, 0, "Input Type"}, {0 -> "Locator Points", 
      1 -> "Table"}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}
    , Button["Update"
     , status = Style["updating ...", Darker@Blue, 14, Bold]; 
     FinishDynamic[]; iUpdate = iUpdate + 1;
     , Method -> "Queued"
     ]
    , Delimiter (*=======================*)
    , Style["Export points", Black, Italic,  12]
    , Button["Export"
     , exportPoints[xyData];
     FinishDynamic[];
     iUpdate = iUpdate + 1;
     , Method -> "Queued"
     ]
    , Delimiter (*=======================*)
    , Style["Reset", Black, Italic,  12]
    , Button["Reset"
     , status = Style["updating ...", Darker@Blue, 14, Bold];
     xyData = initPts[npts];
     iCount = 0;
     iUpdate = 0;
     status = Style["Ready to Start", Darker@ Green, Bold];
     FinishDynamic[];
     iUpdate = iUpdate + 1;
     , Method -> "Queued"
     ]
    , {{npts, 7, "N pts"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
    (*future use:  track iUpdate to trigger long calculations*)
    , {iUpdate, None}
    , ControlPlacement :> {Left, Left}
    , TrackedSymbols :> {iUpdate, inputType}
    , Initialization :> (
      xyData = initPts[7];
      iCount = 0;
      iUpdate = 0;
      status = Style["Ready to Start", Darker@ Green, Bold];
      )
    , SynchronousUpdating -> False
    ]
   ];

Button["start Test", CellPrint@testManip ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command given by -b3m2a1. Add a

```
Dynamic[data]
```

If you edit the Number for China to Blank in the TableView, that is backspace over 21 700 000.

The Dynamic[data] on my system running on MacOS shows

```
{{Paris, France, 2 200 000}, {New York, US, 8 500 000}, {Beijing, China, 2}}
```

Clearly the 2 is wrong, I have had other issues with this Function where it does not play nicely with Dynamic, unfortunately as it stands I think its unusable if used together with Dynamic.